# C Program Crashing, not sure why?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main () {

int dice1; //declaring variables
int dice2;
int dice3;
int dice4;
int dice5;
int rolls = 0;
int diceRolls = 0;
bool reroll1 = false;
bool reroll2 = false;
bool reroll3 = false;
bool reroll4 = false;
bool reroll5 = false;
char confirm1; //no arrays, as mentioned in the rubric :) ...
char confirm2;
char confirm3;
char confirm4;
char confirm5;

srand(time(0)); //seeding

printf("DICE 1\t"); //formatting so the users know which dice is which for later
printf("DICE 2\t");
printf("DICE 3\t");
printf("DICE 4\t");
printf("DICE 5\n");

dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
printf("%d\t", dice1);

dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
printf("%d\t", dice2);

dice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
printf("%d\t", dice3);

dice4 = rand() % 6 + 1;
printf("%d\t", dice4);

dice5 = rand() % 6 + 1;
printf("%d\t\n", dice5);

while ((dice1 != dice2) || (dice2 != dice3) || (dice3 != dice4) || (dice4 != dice5)) { //The loop determines that if Yahtzee is not achieved, it will reroll until it is

    rolls ++;

    printf("Reroll die 1?(y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c", confirm1);
    if (tolower(confirm1) == 'y') {
       reroll1 = true;
       dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    }

    printf("Reroll die 2?(y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c", confirm2);
    if (tolower(confirm2) == 'y') {
       reroll2 = true;
       dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    }

    printf("Reroll die 3?(y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c", confirm3);
    if (tolower(confirm3) == 'y') {
       reroll3 = true;
       dice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    }

    printf("Reroll die 4?(y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c", confirm4);
    if (tolower(confirm4) == 'y') {
       reroll4 = true;
       dice4 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    }

    printf("Reroll die 5?(y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c", confirm5);
    if (tolower(confirm5) == 'y') {
       reroll5 = true;
       dice5 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    }

    if (reroll1) {
        printf("%d\t", dice1);
    } 

    if (reroll2) {
        printf("%d\t", dice2);
    }

    if (reroll3) {
        printf("%d\t", dice3);
    }

    if (reroll4) {
       printf("%d\t", dice4);
    }

    if (reroll5) {
        printf("%d\t\n", dice5);
    }       
}

system("cls"); //clear screen for a better look

diceRolls = rolls * 5; //calculating dice rolls

printf("STATS\n"); //shows user stats
printf("Amount of rolls to achieve Yahtzee!: %d\n", rolls);
printf("Number of dice rolled: %d", diceRolls);

return 0;
}
```

Sorry about the indenting first of all. It is not so neat. This program generates "rolls" 5 die, and tries to get a Yahtzee. The user then is given the option to decide what to reroll. No arrays are allowed in this program, or functions. Now, on to the question. I am having a problem with my code as the program just crashes the first time I try to enter something, which is right after the while loop. When I tried to debug, it seems like scanf is the issue here, but I'm not sure what to change to let the code function, and am not sure what I am doing wrong in the code, since I've been learning C at school for close to a month now.

Thank you,

Kai

Comment: As an aside, `bool`, `true`, and `false` are not valid in C. You should put `#include <stdbool.h>` if you want this to compile in compliant C compilers.

Answer (score 6):

`scanf` takes the address of the variable to write user input to the variable. You are only passing the variable name (value) and not the address. `&` is the operator, which when prefixed to the variable name, gives address of that variable.

So correct way of using `scanf` is as below and this would solve your problem. Use the same for other `scanf` statements in your program.

```
scanf("%c", &confirm1);
```

Comment: Yes, I thought that was only for integers. I tried this yesterday and it worked. I understand, thank you.